# Fair 2d game movement collision arbitration

Tags: 2d, collision-detection

I'm trying to create a 'fair' collision detection system for a 2d sprite game, but I'm finding it more difficult than I initially expected. By 'fair', I mean that no moveable object is given movement priority over another on a single game update:

e.g.
A--> 50px <--B (if b and a have equal speeds, they each should move 25pix before colliding and stopping)

As opposed to greedy algorithms, which might just move A first, and then cancel B's movement because A is already there.

2 cases are quite easy to handle, but I'm running into problems when I have multiple objects colliding.

e.g (only velocities shown).

```
     B
     |
     |<--C 
A--> v
```

Where A,B,and C objects can all be different sizes

Basically, I'm looking for ideas on how to approach this problem. My current approach has become too complicated, and I am interested in discussing some other approaches that I nay not have thought of.

Comment: Have you considered posting your question on Stack Overflow's new section, http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/ ?

Answer (score 1):

If you're moving something and then checking for a collision, as you say, it will never be fair.  So why not move *everything*, and whilst moving an entity, if there is a collision, flag it as such.  Once you're done moving everything, you can have a look at all collisions and decide what to do next based on all of them (e.g, move them all equally away so that they no longer collide).